# I created a github pages site some time ago, but it automatically adds "visibility : hidden !important" tag to one of the divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, github-pages

This is the code that I wrote originally

`<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <a href="portfolio_item_2.html"><img class="card-img-top"           src="assets/pages/img/works/ads1.png" alt=""></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title text-center">
                            <a href="portfolio_item_2.html" style="color:#4e4e4f">ADS College Information System</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p class="card-text text-center">ADS CIS is a web based app that allows you to control the flow of information in an education institution with minimal efforts.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>`

This is what is being generated in the  part

```
<a href="portfolio_item_2.html"><img class="card-img-top" src="assets/pages/img/works/ads1.png" alt="" style="visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;" width="0" height="0"></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything like removing the classes from the tag? Removing any JavaScript files that might be modifying the elements?

Comment: I have 3 other divs just like this, but this is the only one being modified. Even if I try to change the order of the divs, this is the only one that gets modified

Comment: There are no divs in your example code. You need to improve your question to include the divs and possibly a snippet of the isolated code doing the strange behaviour. On StackOverflow you have to show that you have made a reasonable effort to attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: **<a href="portfolio_item_2.html"><img class="card-img-top" src="assets/pages/img/works/ads1.png" alt="" style="visibility: visible; display: flex(or whatever you want); px;"></a>**

You had **display: important** in your code, which is invalid. Maybe try removing the "important" and it won't flag it like that?

Comment: Well the thing is, in my original code, I didn't write the !important or even the style="" part.

Comment: Can you link to a page with it reproduced live? That would help diagnose the issue.

Comment: https://dbc2201.github.io/appdorks/index.html